# ROC curve for decision tree using tree package

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree, roc

I am using the `tree` package in R to make a decision tree, but for doing the ROC curve for the model I need the predicted probabilities and I cannot find the way to obtain it, I just get the predicted response. My code is the following, where Status is the dependent variable (which is "good" or "bad"), my dataset is called "dd" and "learn" is the subset for learning and "-learn" means the subset for testing.

```
tree.dd=tree(Status~.,dd,subset=learn)

tree.test.prob <- predict (tree.dd, newdata = dd[-learn,])

pred = prediction(tree.test.prob, dd[-learn,]$Status)
```

I need pred to be probabilities not responses.

Comment: It is incorrect that decision trees do not output probabilities. Try `?predict.tree` The "Value" section starts out  `If type = "vector": vector of predicted responses or, if the response is a factor, matrix of predicted class probabilities. `

Comment: Where are you getting the function `prediction` ? tree.test.prob should already be a matrix of probabilities.

Comment: thanks for correction @G5W

Comment: Thank you, I was obtaining responses but I put type="vector" and I obtained probabilities!